# How to send only data (ignore receiving) with nc command (equivalent to --send-only option on redhat)?

Tags: netcat

I am using command "echo "TEST" | nc localhost 1234 --send-only" on Redhat version to Only send data and ignoring received. I could not find --send-only equivalent option for nc command on ubuntu.

Comment: Sounds like an option from nmap's ncat: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/ncat.1.html

Answer (score 1):

As @muru said in the comment, the `ncat` software from the `nmap` has the option that you are searching for (`--send-only`).

Anyway, `echo "TEST" | nc localhost 1234 > /dev/null` will have the same effect, since you have no way to tell the remote machine you don't want it's data.